# Inconsistency between asynchronous search results and table display in Flask

Tags: python

If I search using `piccolo` I get a number of results in the table that coincide with the value of the `LIMIT` set by default (which in my case is set to 100) in the main function, even if I change the value of the LIMIT the number of results remains limited to the default value
 But if I search using `Il Piccolo` the number of results is not limited by default value because it depends on what number you manually set for the LIMIT on the browser (in my index.html I use this selector `<input type="number" id="limit" name="limit" value="{{ limit }}">`)

In this picture you can see that limit is 400 and search term is 'piccolo' and in terminal I see 6 results but in datatables I see only 2 results

[image]

In this 2nd situation I have 6 results when I use same LIMIT (400) but number of results in table is different when I use `Il Piccolo` as search term

[image]

I really don't understand why this happens. 
Ok, this is relevant code: if the 'mode' parameter is set to 'online', the code calls the main function asynchronously to get results from an external source. The results are then processed and filtered, and are subsequently added to the database using an asynchronous function add_new_data_to_db. Processing includes sorting results, applying filters, and managing pagination

```
        @app.route('/get_table_data', methods=['POST'])
        def home():
            try:
                default_topic = 661
                default_limit = 100
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    data = request.get_json()  # Get the JSON data from the request
                    app.logger.debug(f"Received JSON data: {data}")  # Log the received JSON data
                    get_all_filtered_rows = data.get('get_all_filtered_rows', False)
                    draw_str = data.get('draw') if 'draw' in data else '0'
                    draw = int(draw_str) if draw_str is not None else 0
                    ....
                    limit_str = data.get('limit') if 'limit' in data else str(default_limit)
                    limit = int(limit_str) if limit_str.isdigit() else default_limit
                    search_term_datatables = data.get('search')['value'] if 'search' in data and 'value' in data.get('search') else ''
                    search_term_telethon = data.get('search_term') if 'search_term' in data else ''
                    case_insensitive = str(data.get('case_insensitive')).lower() == 'true' if 'case_insensitive' in data else False
                    topic = int(data.get('topic')) if 'topic' in data else default_topic
                    start = int(data.get('start')) if 'start' in data else 0
                    length = int(data.get('length')) if 'length' in data else 10
                    
                    ......

                    if mode == 'online':
                        result_tuples = loop.run_until_complete(main(start_date, end_date, limit, search_term_telethon, case_insensitive, topic))
                        result = [{'file_name': file_name, 'message_link': message_link, 'message_date': message_date} for file_name, message_link, message_date in result_tuples]
        
                        def add_new_data_to_db():
                            with app.app_context():
                                for file_name, message_link, message_date in result_tuples:  
                                    
                                    if search_term_telethon in file_name:
                                        exists = db.session.query(DataOnline.file_name).filter_by(file_name=file_name).scalar() is not None
                                        if not exists:
                                            new_data = DataOnline(file_name=file_name, message_link=message_link, topic=topic, date=message_date)  
                                            db.session.add(new_data)
                                db.session.commit()
                                
                        future = executor.submit(add_new_data_to_db)
                        future.result()  # Attendi che il task sia completato
                        query = db.session.query(DataOnline)
                        query = query.order_by(DataOnline.date.desc())
                        if search_term_telethon:
                            search_term_telethon = f"%{search_term_telethon}%"
                            query = query.filter(DataOnline.file_name.like(search_term_telethon))

                        for order_spec in order:
                            column_index = order_spec['column']
                            direction = order_spec['dir']
                            column_name = column_map[column_index]
                            if column_name == 'message_link':
                                
                                column = cast(DataOnline.message_link.op('REGEXP')('/([^/]*)$'), Integer)
                            else:
                                column = getattr(DataOnline, column_name)
                            if direction == 'asc':
                                query = query.order_by(column.asc())
                            else:
                                query = query.order_by(column.desc())
        
                        if topic:
                            query = query.filter(DataOnline.topic == topic)
        
                        if start_date and end_date:
                            
                            query = query.filter(DataOnline.date.between(start_date, end_date))
z
                        records_total = query.count()
        
                        if get_all_filtered_rows:
                            # Se get_all_filtered_rows è true, restituisci tutti i risultati filtrati
                            all_filtered_results = [{'id': data['id'], 'file_name': data['file_name'], 'message_link': data['message_link']} for data in query.all()]
                            response = jsonify({
                                'draw': draw,
                                'recordsTotal': records_total,
                                'recordsFiltered': records_total,
                                'data': all_filtered_results
                            })
                        else:
                            
                            pagination = query.paginate(page=(start // length) + 1, per_page=length, error_out=False)
 
                            response = jsonify({
                                'draw': draw,
                                'recordsTotal': records_total,
                                'recordsFiltered': records_total,
                                'data': [{'id': data['id'], 'file_name': data['file_name'], 'message_link': data['message_link']} for data in paged_results]
                            })
    ....
                print(result)  
                result_message = f"Trovati {len(result)} risultati" if result else "Nessun risultato trovato"
                return render_template('index.html', result=result, result_message=result_message, start_date=start_date_str, end_date=end_date_str, limit=limit, search_term=search_term_telethon, case_insensitive='on' if case_insensitive else 'off', topic=topic, mode=mode, default_topic=default_topic, default_limit=default_limit)
            else:  # GET request
                result = [(data.file_name, data.message_link) for data in Data.query.all()]
                print(result)  
                return render_template('index.html', result=result, case_insensitive='on', default_topic=default_topic, default_limit=default_limit)
```

main function is this: this uses the Telethon library to connect to Telegram, get messages from a specific conversation, and filter messages that contain media (e.g. documents). The results are processed, with file names and message links obtained

```
async def main(start_date=None, end_date=None, limit=100, search_term="", case_insensitive=False, topic=None):
    if start_date is None:
        start_date = datetime.datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1)
    if end_date is None:
        end_date = datetime.datetime(year=2100, month=12, day=31)

    if case_insensitive:
        search_term = search_term.lower()

    print(f"start_date: {start_date}, end_date: {end_date}, limit: {limit}, search_term: {search_term}, case_insensitive: {case_insensitive}, topic: {topic}")

    client = TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash)
    if client is not None:
        async with client:
            anime_topic_message = await client.get_messages(1867911973, ids=int(topic))
            anime_messages = await client.get_messages(1867911973, reply_to=anime_topic_message.id, limit=limit)
            media_messages = [message for message in anime_messages if message.media is not None and start_date <= message.date.replace(tzinfo=None) <= end_date]

            results = []
            for message in media_messages:
                message_link = f"https://t.me/lasoffittadownloads/{message.id}"
                if isinstance(message.media, types.MessageMediaDocument):
                    for attribute in message.media.document.attributes:
                        if isinstance(attribute, DocumentAttributeFilename):
                            file_name = attribute.file_name.replace('_', ' ')  # Replace underscores with spaces
                            break
                    else:
                        file_name = "Unknown"
                else:
                    file_name = "Non-document media"
                
                search_terms = search_term.split()  # Split the search term into separate words
                if case_insensitive:
                    search_terms = [term.lower() for term in search_terms]  # Convert to lowercase if case insensitive
                    file_name_to_search = file_name.lower()
                else:
                    file_name_to_search = file_name

                if all(term in file_name_to_search for term in search_terms):  # Check if all search terms are in the file name
                    results.append((file_name, message_link, message.date.replace(tzinfo=None)))  
            print(f"results: {results}")  
            return results
        if client.is_connected():
            await client.disconnect()
```